# How can i use SQL Select Insert to copy rows from one table to another

Tags: php, sql, database

Hey guys am having a nightmare trying to figure out how to copy all the rows from a select query and insert to another table.

[image: desc wp_rg_lead_detail]

My query returns this result after running this query
SELECT wp_rg_lead.id, wp_rg_lead.created_by, wp_usermeta.meta_key, wp_usermeta.meta_value, wp_usermeta.user_id from `wp_rg_lead` inner join `wp_usermeta` on wp_rg_lead.id = wp_usermeta.user_id where wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'parents_id' and  wp_rg_lead.id = 12;
[image: Query result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select into an existing table use the following format:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
(column1,column2, etc...)
SELECT wp_rg_lead.id, 
           wp_rg_lead.created_by, 
           wp_usermeta.meta_key,
           wp_usermeta.meta_value, 
           wp_usermeta.user_id 
    FROM wp_rg_lead 
    inner join wp_usermeta on wp_rg_lead.id = wp_usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'parents_id' and wp_rg_lead.id = 12;
```

Alternatively if you want to select them into a brand new table you can use this formate to create the table then insert the values:

```
SELECT wp_rg_lead.id, 
               wp_rg_lead.created_by, 
               wp_usermeta.meta_key,
               wp_usermeta.meta_value, 
               wp_usermeta.user_id
        INTO destination_table 
        FROM wp_rg_lead 
        inner join wp_usermeta on wp_rg_lead.id = wp_usermeta.user_id 
        WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'parents_id' and wp_rg_lead.id = 12;
```

In either query you need to change the destination_table to the new table name. In the first query you need to supply column names as well.

Comment: is the column1 the name of the columns or it it the value to be inserted in the destination table

Comment: It is the names of the columns in the destination table. They must be in the same order as the data you getting from your select statement.

Comment: Hilton thanks it has worked :) you've saved me big time

Comment: No problem...and I wish my last name was Hilton ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcolumns) select * from yourothertable
```